# Cant click or move controls while in master view

Tags: delphi

Developing Android app in Delphi XE 8 I create multi device application and I placed the controls in master view now I can not move or even click on any control while master view is selected but I can move the controls if I created another view like Android 4" phone !! why is that ?

[image]

**Update:**
I opened now another Android project then when I returned to my project that has the problem I found that I am able to select and move the controls in the master view again !! Why is this behavior ?

Comment: +1 It depends in which view you dropped the control, Also you cant change the names or any property of that  control.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAljehani I dropped the controls in the master view why I can not move them ?

Comment: You'll find your answer in here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628168/cant-delete-controls-in-delphi-xe7)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAljehani thanks I already found this question but it is not my case